# MATLAB: Vectorize for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, simulink

I wanted to vectorize this piece of code. Is it possible to do this? I tried finding a solution, but I was not able to find any good result on google.

```
for pos=length1+1:length
    X1(pos) = sim(net1, [demandPred(pos), demand(pos-1), X1(pos-1), X1(pos-2)]')';
    X2(pos) = sim(net1, [demandPred(pos), demand(pos-1), X2(pos-1), X2(pos-2)]')';
end
```

Thanks in advance. :)

**Edit 1:**

The model which I am going to simulate is a simple GRNN.

```
net1 = newgrnn([demand(169:trainElem), demand(169-1:trainElem-1), X1(169 - 1:trainElem - 1), X1(169 - 2:trainElem - 2)]', 0.09);
```

Comment: Just an observation - You should never use the matlab built-in function `length` as a variable. I am not overly familiar with simulink, but perhaps this block could allow you to do this? http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/selector.html

Comment: First, why do you want to vectorize this code?  Specifically, what benefits are you hoping to gain?  Understanding your motivation might influence the best approach to take. Also, are you able to edit your Simulink model or are you looking for a vectorized solution that only requires changing the MATLAB code the you provided?

Comment: @grungetta: I had learnt that vectorizing the code would reduce it's runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Can Simulink models be vectorized? Sometimes.
Can ***your*** Simulink model be vectorised? It's impossible to tell without seeing the model -- and how it is being called from m-code (as you've shown in your question) is no indication.

An example of vectorization would be: consider a model with signal s1 that gets added to constant K, and assume that you need to run the models for different values if K.  You could use a loop (like the m-code you show) and run the model for each individual required value for K.  Alternatively, you can make K a vector, in which case all values would get added to s1 and the result would be a vector of signals s1+K(1), s1+K(2),..., s1+K(n), and the model only needs to be executed once for all of these summations to occur.

But, whether that sort of thing can be done in your model cannot be determined without seeing the model.